# Difference between p_filesz and p_memsz of Elf32_Phdr

Tags: elf

I don't understand the exact difference between the `p_filesz` and `p_memsz` fields of `Elf32_Phdr`.

Can anyone help me understand this?

From `man elf`, I see the below definitions of `p_filesz` and `p_memsz` but they are not completely clear to me.

> p_filesz : This member gives the number of bytes in the file image of the segment; it may be
> zero.
>
> p_memsz : This member gives the number of bytes in the memory image of the segment; it
> may be zero.

What exactly are "file image" and "memory image"?

Comment: I think now I understand the difference between p_memsz and p_filesz. p_filesz tells the actual/exact size of of this lodable segment in the elf file, whereas p_memsz is the total size of the the segment in memory. So, this condition (p_filesz <= p_memsz) should always gets fulfilled. other wise segments overlap will happen.  Can someone tell why a loadable section needs more bytes in memory then p_filesz? doesn't it waste memory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you've already stated in your comment, the `p_filesz` field corresponds to the segment's size in bytes in the file, whereas the `p_memsz` is the segment's in-memory size. The reason why `p_memsz` is greater than (or equal to) `p_filesz` is that a loadable segment may contain a `.bss` section, which contains uninitialized data. It would be wasteful to store this data on disk, and therefore it only occupies space once the ELF file is loaded into memory. This fact is indicated by the `SHT_NOBITS` type of the `.bss` section.

As per the ELF specification, in the case where `p_memsz` is greater than `p_filesz`, the extra bytes following the segment's initialized area are defined to hold the value 0.

Comment: Does that mean that a single entry `LOAD` entry in the program header table can correspond to more than one line in the `/proc/<PID>/maps` file?